# Is there difference between `setInternalErrorPage` and `error-page` tag in web.xml for wicket application?

Tags: java, wicket, web.xml

With wicket is is possible to set 500 in to ways:

1. In `WicketApplication` class like that
   getApplicationSettings().setInternalErrorPage(MyError500.class);
2. Via "classical" way in `web.xml`:

   `<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/404</location>
   </error-page>`

Note that in case of `web.xml` url `/404` is mapped to same Error page.

Could someone provide me a difference? Is it enough to use just `web.xml` with page url mapping or it is neccessary to use both files?

Answer (score 0):

404 is when your user hits an url for which there is no page/resource/servlet.

Internal error page is 500.

Wicket will prefer its application setting. Depending on another setting (org.apache.wicket.settings.ExceptionSettings#getUnexpectedExceptionDisplay()) Wicket could be configured to use /500 from web.xml.

Any other non-Wicket Servlet/Filter in this application may have its own logic or fallback to /500.